# Use Webpack/NPM Combo to require additional files within a module

Tags: javascript, module, npm, uikit, require

## The Scenario

We've got a Laravel 5.3 and UIKit 2 Combination setup using Elixir/webpack to bundle our JS.

By default laravel comes with a `/resources/js/bootstrap.js` (not twitter related)

This file is used to include dependencies, so currently it looks like

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.UI = window.UIkit = require('uikit');
```

However because UIKit is component based, and lets you bolt on extra functionality, e.g modals/tooltips you must then include the extra js component.

These are stored as `/node_modules/uikit/dist/js/components/tooltip.js`

This means I'm currently doing

```
window.UI = window.UIkit = require('uikit');
require('../../../node_modules/uikit/dist/js/components/tooltip');
```

As you can see there is a nasty very presumptuous `../../../` at the start, which makes me uncomfortable incase something happens and this is not the path.

## The Question

Is there a more effective/stable/less-error-prone way to include these extra files? e.g

```
require('uikit')->path('components/tooltip');
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Classically moments after posting the question, started digging more through Nodes documentation and came across

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Which explains you can access submodules via defining the module first, then the local path the extra files.

e.g

```
require('MODULE/path/to/submodule');
```

So in UIkits example it would be

```
require('uikit/dist/js/components/tooltip');
```

Hopefuly this will help anybody else.